# How can I access POST data and then delete it in CakePHP?

Tags: php, android, cakephp, post, request

I am building an Android application which connects to my remote server. I am allowing users to add new things but they must also be authenticated before they are allowed to add. Here is an example of what they add:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_NAME, name));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_ADDRESS, address));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_TYPE, type));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_DIFFICULTY, difficulty));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_TERRAIN, terrain));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_LONG, Double.toString(currentLng)));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_LAT, Double.toString(currentLat)));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_UID, Integer.toString(2)));

//Retrieve hash and id to identify authenticate user
UserAuth auth = new UserAuth(AddSpot.this);
HashMap<String,String> session = auth.getUserDetails();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_UID, session.get("id")));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SharedVariables.TAG_HASH, session.get("hash")));
```

As you can see, in the first part, I am storing the things the user is adding themselves, however, I then also pass on the user id and then the token/hash into the POST data as can be seen in the last part. My problem is, I don't want to add everything into the database table with `$this->Location->save($this->request->data)`. Instead I want to be able to pick out the user id and the hash and remove it and then save it all the other stuff. How can I do this in CakePHP?

This is my method in CakePHP right now:

```
function add()
{               
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $response = array();
        $this->loadModel('User');
        if($this->User->validateHash($id, $hash))
        {   
            //Do some logic to remove id and hash from request

            $this->Location->create();
            //Save data from POST
            if ($this->Location->save($this->request->data))
            {
                //Successfully saved
                $this->response->statusCode(200);
            } 
            else
            {
                //Error in saving
                $this->response->statusCode(500);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            //Does their hash match? No, then they are unauthorized to add
            $this->response->statusCode(401);
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('response'));
    $this->set('_serialize', array('response'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?:

```
unset($this->request->data['YourModel']['id']);
unset($this->request->data['YourModel']['hash']);
```

Comment: Ah yes, obviously! Silly me. I'm wondering, does it matter if I remove  those values or not if those fields don't exist inside the table? I.e. if I just call save without unsetting them?

Comment: You can save any data you want - if it doesn't have a matching field, it won't be put into the database, but it shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll explicitly unset it anyway just to be clear

Comment: Note that `$this->request->data` will no longer be accessible as a public property in CakePHP 4.0.0.